# My __str__ is too long, best way to write it

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I've this __str__  method in one of my classes but in my opinion it looks a bit too long in my code for python conventions and autopep is not giving me any hints.

So I was wondering what would be the most *pythonic* way to type it.

I need the break lines because solution and table shapes are 52 and 52x52 respectively.

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Cost solution : " + str(self.cost) + "\nSolution: " + str(self.solution) + "\n\nTable:" + str(self.table)
```

Comment: "Most pythonic" is certainly subjective, but since you have multiple lines, I'd probably go with some sort of `return "\n".join([<list of strings>])`

Comment: python 3.6 allows f-strings. short & easy to read

Comment: @jewards Should've asked it better at the end I just want a solution that's under PEP8's limit per line.
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3.6 introduced f-strings, which allow for short strings & format

```
class foo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.cost = 12
    self.solution = "easy"
    self.table = "no"
  def __str__(self):
    return f"Cost: {self.cost}\nSolution: {self.solution}\nTable: {self.table}"

f = foo()
print(str(f))
```

Comment: I like the readability, better than messing up with the indentation in my opinion thanks!.

Comment: as long as you don't run this code on less than python 3.6 you'll be fine :) and performance is also better (less parameter/variable lookups)

Answer (score 4):

```
def __str__(self):
    pattern = '''
    Cost solution: {}
    Solution: {}
    Table: {}
    '''
    return pattern.format(self.cost, self.solution, self.table)
```

If you don't want extra tabs in output while using multiline strings you need to remove tabs in your code in them.

```
class Test(object):
    pattern = '''
Cost solution: {}
Solution: {}
Table: {}
'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.cost = 0;
        self.solution = 'StackOverflow'
        self.table = '1|2|3|4'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pattern.format(self.cost, self.solution, self.table)

print Test()
```

Comment: btw I think the OP wants a blank line before `Table:`.

Comment: @quamrana I think he can figurate this out

Comment: This one looks really nice, but sadly it's taking the tabs before the text giving a weird [display](https://i.imgur.com/djZiAOz.png). nevermind you noticed first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `str.format` method to combine strings in a more *pythonic* way, but it is still quite long.

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Cost solution: {}\nSolution: {}\n\nTable {}".format(self.cost, self.solution, self.table)
```

You can split it over two lines after the end of the format string if you need to by using the backward slash.